# Avoiding endless tail for Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When creating a generic container is there a better way than running an endless ping or tail to keep the container from exiting?

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python-pip

VOLUME /flask

EXPOSE 8080:8080

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

All other attempts at keeping a process running exit with code 0, after running `docker-compose up`

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of keeping a container running that has no useful process?

Comment: @JasonMartin this is all for building custom images from a Dockerfile and containers from docker-compose based on that image. Say that you are building a container that doesn't have a useful process yet, but needs to be in a running state in order to test commands against, to further flesh out the container. If the Dockerfile doesn't have a proper CMD or Entrypoint when docker compose is called it will exit; making it difficult to then log in to the container and execute commands or code. I just felt it was a little bit of a hack to hold it open with tail or ping.

Comment: Sleep 9999999999 is probably reasonable as well. The container is already in a sort of nonstandard state since its being held open for testing, so the sleep or tail is no worse.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior for "docker-compose up".  From the docs ([here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/))

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

Comment: No matter if it's in the foreground or background `docker-compose -d ` will not hold a container open once the process has exited. The -d option will push the process to the background and give you access back to the command prompt; yes that part is correct.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks for clarifying.  Containers exiting when the process is complete is expected behavior.  ;)  (Yes, I know you are trying to get around that default behavior) :)